# How to change line colors in line chart using Altair

Tags: python, altair

I'd like to change the colors of the lines in this line chart but when I created a code to do that, nothing happened. I'd like to change the colors so the lines are green and yellow instead of orange and blue:

[image: 1]

This is the code I'm using to design the visual with my attempt at changing the colors that didn't work but still populated this chart:

```
# team names
domain = ['☘️', '']
# line colors
range_ = ['gold','green']

# creating the line chart
tweet = alt.Chart(ndf).mark_line().encode(
    x='average(datetime)',
    y='tweet_count',
    stroke='team',
    color=alt.Color('team',scale=alt.Scale(domain=domain,range=range_)))

tweet
```

Comment: Could you provide the full reproducible example including how you create the base chart? You can see from the docs that it works with `range=`, e.g. [change this example to use a line mark](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#color-domain-and-range)

Comment: That is what I based my code on originally but it didn't work out. I realized I added base but I don't have a base chart created. Do I need to have one in order to change the colors? I updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `stroke` encoding or set it to use the same range as the `color` encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying this:

```
color=alt.Color('team', scale={"range": ["yellow", "orange"]})
```